# Sending an email using oauth and send_mail in django

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

I have followed the steps in:
http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/XoauthDotPyRunThrough

and generated oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, and xoauth as well.

Now the qustion is - how can I send an email with information above?
I have configured smtp host, and port, which works, but I would rather not like to process original password.

I mean something like:

```
send_mail('Subject here', 'mesage here', 'me@gmail.com',
        ['you@gmail.com','him@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False,
        auth_user="me@gmail.com", auth_password="password")
```

works perfectly.

Would be grateful for any help.