# Sending email using send_mail and oauth2.0(Modern authentication) in Django

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, smtp

send_mail in Django allows SMTP. I want to check if OAuth2.0 is supported in send_mail option in Django

Django version 2.4.57

```
connection = EmailBackend(
            host=host,
            port=port,
            username=username,
            password=password,
            use_tls=tls,
            use_ssl=ssl,
        )
connection.open()

msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_mail, to_mails, connection=connection)
msg.send()
```

I am trying to use send_mail option in Django to send emails. I use SMTP connection to provide username and password for the SMTP server. As many companies are disabling SMTP relays for emails, I would like to implement modern authentication for sending mails from Django.
I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338849/sending-an-email-using-oauth-and-send-mail-in-django) asked 11 years ago but there's no solution given. Couldn't comment in that question, so asking as a separate question.